# How to use tagName and Menu separator?

Tags: ember.js

I am using `tagName` in my Ember template and a menu separator `||` but rendering is not quite what is expected.  e.g Mouse pointer doesn't turn to Hand when pointing `About or Home` and `||` appears at the end of `About`. Where as `Products` appear alright.  What is wrong?

[image]

```
  <script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='application'>
    <div class='navbar navbar-default fixed-top'>
      <div class='container'>
        {{#link-to 'index' class='navbar-brand'}}Ember{{/link-to}}
        <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
          {{#link-to 'index' tagName='li'}}Home{{/link-to}}
          ||
          {{#link-to 'about' tagName='li'}}About{{/link-to}}
          <li>{{#link-to 'products'}}Products{{/link-to}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't wrap your menu items in `<li>`:

```
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
      <li>{{#link-to 'index' tagName='li'}}Home{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>||</li>
      <li>{{#link-to 'about' tagName='li'}}About{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to 'products'}}Products{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
```